# Bash command substitution on remote host

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm trying to run a bash script that ssh's onto a remote host and stops the single docker container that is running.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

ssh <machine> <<EOF

container=$(docker ps | awk 'NR==2' | awk '{print $1;}')

docker stop $container

EOF
```

However, I get the following error:

```
stop.sh: line 4: docker: command not found
```

When I do this manually (ssh to the machine, run the commands) all is fine, but when trying to do so by means of a script I get the error.  I guess that my command substitution syntax is incorrect and I've searched and tried all kinds of quotes etc but to no avail.

Can anyone point me to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Heredocs perform parameter expansion of their contents, so your `$(docker ps ...)` and `$container` evaluations are happening before the code ever gets to ssh's stdin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `<<'EOF'` (or `<<\EOF` -- quoting only the first character will have the same effect) when starting your heredoc to prevent its expansions from being evaluated locally.

---

BTW, personally, I'd write this a bit differently:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
ssh "$1" bash <<'EOF'
{ read; read container _; } < <(docker ps)
docker stop "$container"
EOF
```

The first `read` consumes the first line of `docker ps` output; the second extracts only the first column -- using bash builtins only.

Comment: Worked like a charm Charles.  Many thanks!

Comment: @user1061799, glad to help. BTW, I've amended in a proposed alternate form for the script. If you did still want to use `awk`, though, you could use `awk 'NR == 2 { print $1 }'` to combine the two invocations into one line.

Comment: That's neater alright.  Thanks again Charles